# Visual Studio Community 2013 change app default pictures

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio, silverlight

I don't know how I can change Windows Phone Silverlight app default project pictures (`Assets` folder). If I just change pictures in the folder, the Windows App Certification Kit test failed.

Can I change pictures with Visual Studio?

In `WMAppManifast.xaml` and `Package.appxmanifest` are missing the `Assets` tab.

The error message:

> Error Found: The branding validation test encountered the following errors:
>   * Image file StoreLogo.png is a default image.
>   * Image file Logo.png is a default image.
>   * Image file SquareTile71x71.png is a default image.
>   * Image file SquareTile150x150.png is a default image.
>   * Image file SplashScreen.png is a default image.
>
> Impact if not fixed: Windows Phone Store apps are expected to be
>   complete and fully functional. Apps using the default images, e.g.
>   from templates or SDK samples, present a poor user experience and
>   cannot be easily identified in the store catalog.
>
> How to fix: Replace default images with something more distinct and
>   representative of your app.

Comment: Rename them everywhere

Comment: I do it, but it is not work.

Comment: Can you post a project sample?

Comment: Yes. I share with OneDrive: [link](http://1drv.ms/1FXfLgj)